# How to reconfigure Docker Trusted Registry 2.x.x to use CEPH FS mount instead of NFS and other traditional storage?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, storage, docker

I am having trouble trying to reconfigure my DTR container to try and use a CEPH FS mount we created to act as a storage backend for our image repository.

The Docs are very vague on this and nothing exactly explains on how to do it.
Has anyone yet connected the dots?

Answer (score 0):

Since I was able to implement the DTR backend storage using CEPH FS in my organisation, I would like to answer how we connected the dots for others who'd want to try this out in future.

```
docker run --rm -it docker/dtr:2.x.x reconfigure --dtr-storage-volume /path/to/CEPHFS/mount --ucp-insecure-tls
```

In case you want to know how to create a CEPHFS mount on your linux machine, please refer the docs at [here](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/cephfs/).